# Quasilinear utility functions

Tags: calculus, economics

Is the utility function below quasilinear?

$U(X,Y)=XY+10Y$

I know that an equation of the form $U(X,Y)=f(X)+Y$ is quasilinear but I'm not sure about functions of the form $U(X,Y)=f(X,Y)+Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia says, a utility function is [quasilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasilinear_utility) if can be brought into this form:
$$U(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=x_1+\theta(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$
But you can bring your utility function neither to this
$$U(X,Y)=X+\theta(Y)$$
nor to this
$$U(X,Y)=Y+\theta(X)$$
form. So, I would say: No. (But, hey, I'm no expert in economics, just applying the definition)

Comment: Thanks, so if the function were $U(X,Y)=10XY+Y$ it would be quasilinear?

Comment: No, still not. If it were e.g. $U(X,Y)=10X^2+Y$ or $U(X,Y)=X+e^Y$ or $U(X,Y,Z)=10XZ+Y$ then yes. The problem with $U(X,Y)=10XY+Y$ is that $XY$ still depends on $Y$.